# loading an swf asset in Angular 4 with TSC

Tags: angular, flash, typescript, swfobject

Does anyone know how to load a local swf asset into an Angular application using TypeScript?

I have an `swf` file packaged with the application, and I need to load it inside a `tabSet`.

Thanks

Comment: Not enough info to help you... What have you tried that isn't working? Did you put swf in same folder as application? Did you try to load swf by filename? Any error messages?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. Yes the swf is in the same folder as the application. i tried using the embed tag, but that didnt work. Im not sure how im suppossed to load it. (FYI started learning angular 2 weeks ago)